# Reading text files instead of manually inputting data

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Hi i have a program that allows user to input coordinates to draw a polygon using turtle graphics. However, it gets tiring and cumbersome to do so. I want to include a feature that allows user to input a text file but so far i have no success with it. How do i go about doing it?

Lets say i want a square with coordinates (0,0),(0,100),(100,100)(100,0) with a hole in the polygon coordinates (0,0),(0,20),(20,20),(20,0) with offset of -50.

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5YRa.jpg)

```
import turtle
turtle.setup(640, 380)
import math
import json

import turtle

def get_vertex():
    """Get a vertex by clicking on the screen."""
    turtle.onscreenclick(turtle.goto)

def get_polygon():
    """Get a polygon by clicking on the screen."""
    turtle.speed(0)  # Set turtle speed to fastest
    get_vertex()
    vertices = []
    while True:
        vertex = turtle.pos()
        if vertex in vertices:
            break  # Polygon is complete
        vertices.append(vertex)
        turtle.dot(5)  # Draw a dot at each vertex
    turtle.penup()
    return vertices


def getPolygonVertices(numVertices): #get polygon vertices function
    vertices = []
    for i in range(numVertices):
        try:
            x = int(input(f"Enter x coordinate of vertex {i+1}: "))
            y = int(input(f"Enter y coordinate of vertex {i+1}: "))
            vertices.append((x, y))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Coordinates must be integers.")
            return None
    return vertices


def polygon(vertices): #draw polygon function
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(vertices[0])
    turtle.pd()
    for vertex in vertices:
        turtle.goto(vertex)
    turtle.goto(vertices[0])


def getHoles(numHoles, polygonVertices): #get holes function
    holes = []
    for i in range(numHoles):
        try:
            x = int(input(f"Enter x coordinate of hole {i+1}: "))
            y = int(input(f"Enter y coordinate of hole {i+1}: "))
            if not pointInsidePolygon((x, y), polygonVertices):
                print("Error: Hole must be inside original polygon.")
                return None
            holes.append((x, y))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Coordinates must be integers.")
            return None
    return holes


def pointInsidePolygon(point, vertices, epsilon=1e-9):
    x, y = point
    inside = False
    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        j = (i + 1) % len(vertices)
        if abs((vertices[j][1] - vertices[i][1])*(x - vertices[i][0]) - (vertices[j][0] - vertices[i][0])*(y - vertices[i][1])) < epsilon:
            # point is on the edge of the polygon
            return False
        if ((vertices[i][1] > y) != (vertices[j][1] > y)) and \
           (x < (vertices[j][0] - vertices[i][0]) * (y - vertices[i][1]) / (vertices[j][1] - vertices[i][1]) + vertices[i][0]):
            inside = not inside
    return inside

def offsetPolygon(vertices, offset):
    newVertices = []
    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        j = (i + 1) % len(vertices)
        v1 = vertices[i]
        v2 = vertices[j]
        dx = v2[0] - v1[0]
        dy = v2[1] - v1[1]
        length = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
        if length > 0:
            dx /= length
            dy /= length
            dx *= offset
            dy *= offset
        newVertices.append((v1[0] + dy, v1[1] - dx))
    return newVertices


def hatchPolygon(vertices, lineSpacing=10, angle=0):
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()

    #draw polygon
    polygon(vertices)

    #compute and draw hatch lines
    min_x = min(v[1] for v in vertices)
    max_x = max(v[0] for v in vertices)
    min_y = min(v[1] for v in vertices)
    max_y = max(v[0] for v in vertices)

    #convert angle to radians
    radAngle = math.radians(angle)

    #compute line spacing in x and y direction
    line_spacing_x = lineSpacing * math.cos(radAngle)
    line_spacing_y = lineSpacing * math.sin(radAngle)

    #compute start point
    start_x = float((min_x + line_spacing_x/2) / line_spacing_x) 
    start_y = float((min_y + line_spacing_y/2) / line_spacing_y)
    #compute end point
    end_x = float((max_x - line_spacing_x/2) / line_spacing_x) * line_spacing_x
    end_y = float((max_y - line_spacing_y/2) / line_spacing_y) * line_spacing_y

    #draw hatch lines
    turtle.pu()
    for y in range(int(start_y), int(end_y), int(line_spacing_y)):
        for x in range(int(start_x), int(end_x), int(line_spacing_x)):
            if pointInsidePolygon((x, y), vertices):
                if not any(pointInsidePolygon((x, y), holeVertices) for holeVertices in holesVertices):
                    turtle.goto(x, y)
                    turtle.pd()
                    turtle.goto(x - line_spacing_x * math.tan(radAngle), y + line_spacing_y)
                    turtle.pu()

    turtle.done()


#Main
   
# Read the JSON file
with open('polygon.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Extract the polygon vertices from the data dictionary
polygonVertices = data['polygon']

# Extract the hole verticles from the data dictionary
holesVertices = data['hole']

# draw the polygon
polygon(polygonVertices)

# draw the holes
for hole in holesVertices:
    polygon(holesVertices)

# offset the polygon and draw the resulting polygon
offset = float(input("Enter offset distance: "))
offsetVertices = offsetPolygon(polygonVertices, offset)
polygon(offsetVertices)

# hatch the polygon
hatchPolygon(polygonVertices, 10, 45)
```

Comment: rather than call `polygonVertices = getPolygonVertices(n)` you will get those points from a file. I recommend a json file that you can read in as a python dictionary. Then you will be able to do something like : `polygonVertices = data["polygon"]` Give it a try using the `json` module and let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: @JonSG

appreciate the help :) i have added in this code and am able to read the json module. however i am having some complications and im afraid that it has to do with my def pointInsidePolygon, in reading the json file.

i have updated the code in my original post and added in the error messages that i have received

please advice

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python open() function to read a file:

```
TextFile = open(<your filename>)
```

Then you can read get the whole file text / single line text as a string with

```
AllCoordinates = TextFile.read() / CoordinateLine = TextFile.readline()
```

Or you can get a list of strings of each line with

```
CoordinateList = TextFile.readlines()
```

You could then pull the coordinates out of this and plug them in where the user input would be normally.

Remember to close the file after you have read it!

```
TextFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with an instructions file "polygon.json" that looks like this:

```json
{
    "polygon" : [[0, 0], [100, 0], [100, 100], [0, 100]],
    "holes" : [
        [[0, 0], [10, 0], [10, 10], [0, 10]]
    ],
    "offset": -50
}
```

You can make very slight modifications to your code to read and use that file as input. Really the only change is to pass the holes as a parameter to the function that hashes the interior of the polygon.

```py
import json
import math
import turtle
import time

def get_vertex():
    """Get a vertex by clicking on the screen."""
    turtle.onscreenclick(turtle.goto)

def get_polygon():
    """Get a polygon by clicking on the screen."""
    turtle.speed(0)  # Set turtle speed to fastest
    get_vertex()
    vertices = []
    while True:
        vertex = turtle.pos()
        if vertex in vertices:
            break  # Polygon is complete
        vertices.append(vertex)
        turtle.dot(5)  # Draw a dot at each vertex
    turtle.penup()
    return vertices

def getPolygonVertices(numVertices): #get polygon vertices function
    vertices = []
    for i in range(numVertices):
        try:
            x = int(input(f"Enter x coordinate of vertex {i+1}: "))
            y = int(input(f"Enter y coordinate of vertex {i+1}: "))
            vertices.append((x, y))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Coordinates must be integers.")
            return None
    return vertices

def polygon(vertices): #draw polygon function
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(vertices[0])
    turtle.pd()
    for vertex in vertices:
        turtle.goto(vertex)
    turtle.goto(vertices[0])

def getHoles(numHoles, polygonVertices): #get holes function
    holes = []
    for i in range(numHoles):
        try:
            x = int(input(f"Enter x coordinate of hole {i+1}: "))
            y = int(input(f"Enter y coordinate of hole {i+1}: "))
            if not pointInsidePolygon((x, y), polygonVertices):
                print("Error: Hole must be inside original polygon.")
                return None
            holes.append((x, y))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Coordinates must be integers.")
            return None
    return holes

def pointInsidePolygon(point, vertices, epsilon=1e-9):
    x, y = point
    inside = False
    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        j = (i + 1) % len(vertices)
        if abs((vertices[j][1] - vertices[i][1])*(x - vertices[i][0]) - (vertices[j][0] - vertices[i][0])*(y - vertices[i][1])) < epsilon:
            # point is on the edge of the polygon
            return False
        if ((vertices[i][1] > y) != (vertices[j][1] > y)) and \
           (x < (vertices[j][0] - vertices[i][0]) * (y - vertices[i][1]) / (vertices[j][1] - vertices[i][1]) + vertices[i][0]):
            inside = not inside
    return inside

def offsetPolygon(vertices, offset):
    newVertices = []
    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        j = (i + 1) % len(vertices)
        v1 = vertices[i]
        v2 = vertices[j]
        dx = v2[0] - v1[0]
        dy = v2[1] - v1[1]
        length = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
        if length > 0:
            dx /= length
            dy /= length
            dx *= offset
            dy *= offset
        newVertices.append((v1[0] + dy, v1[1] - dx))
    return newVertices

def hatchPolygon(vertices, holesVertices, lineSpacing=10, angle=0):
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()

    #draw polygon
    polygon(vertices)

    #compute and draw hatch lines
    min_x = min(v[1] for v in vertices)
    max_x = max(v[0] for v in vertices)
    min_y = min(v[1] for v in vertices)
    max_y = max(v[0] for v in vertices)

    #convert angle to radians
    radAngle = math.radians(angle)

    #compute line spacing in x and y direction
    line_spacing_x = lineSpacing * math.cos(radAngle)
    line_spacing_y = lineSpacing * math.sin(radAngle)

    #compute start point
    start_x = float((min_x + line_spacing_x/2) / line_spacing_x) 
    start_y = float((min_y + line_spacing_y/2) / line_spacing_y)
    #compute end point
    end_x = float((max_x - line_spacing_x/2) / line_spacing_x) * line_spacing_x
    end_y = float((max_y - line_spacing_y/2) / line_spacing_y) * line_spacing_y

    #draw hatch lines
    turtle.pu()
    for y in range(int(start_y), int(end_y), int(line_spacing_y)):
        for x in range(int(start_x), int(end_x), int(line_spacing_x)):
            if pointInsidePolygon((x, y), vertices):
                if not any(pointInsidePolygon((x, y), holeVertices) for holeVertices in holesVertices):
                    turtle.goto(x, y)
                    turtle.pd()
                    turtle.goto(x - line_spacing_x * math.tan(radAngle), y + line_spacing_y)
                    turtle.pu()

## ------------------------------
# Main
## ------------------------------
turtle.setup(640, 380)
   
# Read the JSON file
with open('polygon.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# draw the polygon
polygon(data['polygon'])

# draw the hole(s)
for hole in data['holes']:
    polygon(hole)

# offset the polygon and draw the resulting polygon
offsetVertices = offsetPolygon(data['polygon'], data['offset'])
polygon(offsetVertices)

# hatch the polygon
hatchPolygon(data['polygon'], data['holes'], 10, 45)

time.sleep(5)
turtle.done()
## ------------------------------
```

That give me:

[image: some polygons]

Which makes me wonder if you have an "off by one" bug but that is your call.

Comment: Thank you, i'm having a look at my code now and doing the debugging :) thank u for all your help